# Get current url in ci

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am making a breadcrumb for my codeigniter using bootstrap but would like to know how to get the current url and so it show the page on my breadcrumbs current_url() not sure how to use this

**Displayed On Controller Index**

```
$data['breadcrumbs'] = array();

$data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
'text' => $this->lang->line('language_key'),
'href' => $this->url->link
);
```

**Displayed On View**

```
<div class="breadcrumb">
<?php foreach ($breadcrumbs as $breadcrumb) { ?>
<li><a href="<?php echo $breadcrumb['href']; ?>"><?php echo $breadcrumb['text']; ?></a></li>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: echo ”$breadcrumb['href'] what does that spit out, and how does it differ from what you want?

Comment: You load the `Helper_URL` class and then call `current_url()`: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html

Comment: I tried this seem to display it  $this->uri->uri_string()

Comment: @Ronni Skansing should link up with current location of url.

Answer (score 0):

yep for example what i would do is create a helper "breadcrumb_helper.php" and place it in your helpers folder (application/helpers/breadcrumb_helper.php). Load it with the auto load config file so that it is loaded via the entire site and can be called inside a view file.

```
<?php
/* This is breadcrumb_helper.php */

function breadcrumbs() {

    //get codeigniter instance as object
    $ci =& get_instance();

    $linkBuild = '';
    $breadcrumbs = '';
    //http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/uri.html
    //the uri class is loaded by the system automatically
    $count = 1;
    $segs = $ci->uri->segment_array();

    //no need to run this on the main page and only show a link to the main page.
    if(count($segs) >= 1) :
        $breadcrumbs .= '<ol class="breadcrumb">';
        $breadcrumbs .= '<li class="home"><a href="' . base_url() . '"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a></li>';
        foreach ($segs as $segment)
        {
            $linkBuild .= $ci->uri->segment($count) . '/';

            if($count <= count($segs)) :
                $breadcrumbs .= '<li><a href="' . base_url() . $linkBuild . '">' . $segment . '</a></li>';
            else :
                $breadcrumbs .= '<li>' . $segment . '</li>';
                $count++;
            endif;
        }
        $breadcrumbs .= '</ol>';
    endif;

    return $breadcrumbs;
}
```

Then in your view file you would just need to run the function like this:

```
<?= breadcrumbs(); ?>
```

And this will give you the current breadcrumb to the page you are on.

Answer (score 0):

Working now

Controller file

```
$data['breadcrumbs'] = array();

$data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
'text' => $this->lang->line('heading_title'),
'href' => $this->uri->uri_string()
);
```

View File

```
<div class="breadcrumb">
<?php foreach ($breadcrumbs as $breadcrumb) { ?>
<li><a href="<?php echo $breadcrumb['href']; ?>"><?php echo $breadcrumb['text']; ?></a></li>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```